# How can I create a random deck of 7 cards every time they are all used?

Tags: unity, c#, random, tetris

I'm trying to create a Tetris like game in C# (Unity) and I've run into quite a problem on how I can generate 7 cards ([tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino)) of which none are the same and when I run out of cards, I regenerate more.

I can kind of see how I could do the regeneration part but I'm very unsure on getting 7 cards for which none are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it happens, I was showing this method to my game mechanics students just this week. :)

One of my favourite ways to work with a deck is using an online version of a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (also called a Knuth shuffle)

```
IEnumerator<T> ShuffleBag<T>(params T[] items) {
    int remaining = items.Length;

    while(true) {
        // Choose a random item from what remains of our deck.
        // (That is, the entries 0...remaining-1)
        int drawIndex = Random.Range(0, remaining);
        T drawnItem = items[drawIndex];

        // Remove the item from the deck by swapping it to the end.
        remaining--;
        items[drawIndex] = items[remaining];
        items[remaining] = drawnItem;

        // Yield the drawn item as our new .Current item,
        // and wait until we're asked to draw again.
        yield return drawnItem;

        // If we're out of cards when we ask for a new one,
        // reshuffle the discards to make a fresh deck.
        if (remaining == 0)
            remaining = items.Length;
    }
}
```

You can set this up like so:

```
var bag = ShuffleBag(
             Tetromino.I,
             Tetromino.O,
             Tetromino.T,
             Tetromino.J, 
             Tetromino.L, 
             Tetromino.S, 
             Tetromino.Z
         );
```

Then draw a new tetromino from the bag like so:

```
bag.MoveNext();
var tetromino = bag.Current;
```

There will always be a new tetromino ready: the bag will automatically reshuffle the discards whenever it gets empty, and give them out in a new random order.

---

Here's the same basic idea, but as a class rather than an iterator, so we can give it a somewhat richer API:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Deck<T> {

    public int Remaining { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get { return _items.Count;  } }
    public int DiscardCount { get { return TotalCount - Remaining; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private List<T> _items;

    // To create an empty deck and .Add() items to it as you go.
    public Deck() {
        _items = new List<T>();
    }

    // To create a deck from the elements passed as constructor arguments.
    public Deck(params T[] items) {
        _items = new List<T>(items);
        Remaining = items.Length;
    }

    // To create a deck from an existing list, array, or other finite enumerable.
    public Deck(IEnumerable<T> items) {
        _items = new List<T>(items);
        Remaining = _items.Count;
    }

    // Shuffle a new card into the deck.    
    public void Add(T item) {
        _items.Add(_items.Count > 0 ? _items[_items.Count - 1] : item);
        _items[Remaining] = item;
        Remaining++;
    }

    // Add an item to the discard pile, so it doesn't come up till the next shuffle.
    public void AddToDiscards(T item) {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    // Draw an item, shuffling if necessary.    
    public T Draw() {
        PreDraw();

        int index = Random.Range(0, Remaining);

        return Draw(index);
    }

    // Draw an item, using your own random source.
    // Useful if you need determinism, or are generating stuff in a background thread.
    public T Draw(System.Random dice) {
        PreDraw();

        int index = (int)(dice.NextDouble() * Remaining);

        return Draw(index);
    }

    // Manually force a reshuffle of any discards.
    public void Shuffle() {
        Remaining = _items.Count;
    }

    // Remove an item, if present (true)
    // Returns false if the item is not in the deck or discards.    
    public bool TryRemove(T item) {
        int index = _items.IndexOf(item);

        if (index < 0) return false;

        if (index < Remaining)
            Remaining--;

        _items.RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }

    // Ensures the deck is in a valid state to draw from, shuffling if needed.
    private void PreDraw() {
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsTrue(_items.Count > 0,
            "Attempted to draw from an empty deck. " +
            "Add at least one item before calling Draw().");

        if (Remaining == 0)
            Shuffle();
    }

    // Do the actual work of pulling the selected item out of the deck,
    // placing it in the discard pile, and keeping the remaining items together.
    private T Draw(int index) {
        T selected = _items[index];

        Remaining--;
        _items[index] = _items[Remaining];
        _items[Remaining] = selected;

        return selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of your tetrominoes, then get a random one out of it, do something with it, then remove it from the list:

```
List<Tetromino> m_list = new List<Tetromino>();

m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #1 here*/);
m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #2 here*/);
m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #3 here*/);
m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #4 here*/);
m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #5 here*/);
m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #6 here*/);
m_list.Add(/* put tetromino #7 here*/);

while(m_list.Count > 0)
{
    int rndNumber = Random.Range(0, m_list.Count);
    // do something with m_list[rndNumber]
    m_list.RemoveAt(rndNumber);
}
```

This way, each item can be used only once, and when the while loop exits, you're sure you've used each one once.